# Como mostrar botones (excel,pdf y print) en Datatables

Tags: javascript, php

Buenas espero me ayuden en lo siguiente. Necesito exportar los datos de un dataTable a Excel y PDF pero me surge un problema con el código, cuando agrego el siguiente script me sale error `. Al querer agregar los buttons.min.js desaparece los datos de mi datatable generandome un error (Uncaught Unknown button type: print).

```js
<script src="../../public/data/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script> 
<script src="../../public/datatables/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../public/datatables/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../public/datatables/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../public/assets/js/pages/be_tables_datatables.js"></script>
```

```css
link href="../../public/datatables/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: Revisa el orden con el que cargas los archivos

Comment: `print` tiene su propio script, creo que tan solo te falta incluirlo.

Comment: gracias, estoy revisando mi codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que tal yo estoy usando datatables en un proyecto quiza te puede servir el orden de mi codigo(estoy usando pdf, excell y impresion) como botones
https://github.com/jpaiton2334/proyecto-titulo/blob/parte2/ultima_ves_visto.php

Comment: Lo raro es que también me da error, al momento de agregar el dataTables.buttons.min.j

Comment: Verifica las rutas  ../../ < - te indica que estás saliendo de dos carpetas, puede que tengas los archivos en otra ruta

Comment: ok, volver e a revisar mi código, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Solucione mi problema con lo siguiente:

```js
<script src=//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js></script>
<script src=//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js></script>
<script src=//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js></script>
<script src=//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js></script>
<script src=//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js></script>
<script src=//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js></script>
<script src=//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/buttons.print.min.js></script>
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
```